# Struggling in passing data from Child to Parent React Component. Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Table`)

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

My objective is to sort table's data according to the column clicked.
In order to to accomplish this goal, I need to pass the information about the `header` clicked from the `child component` `"Table"` to the `parent component` "App".

This is from the `child component` `Table` :

```
  const [keyclicked, setKeyclicked] = React.useState("");

  const [sortOptions, setSortOptions] = React.useState({
    first: "",
    second: ""
  });

  const modalFunct = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (document.getSelection(keyclicked.target).focusNode !== null) {
      console.log(
        document
          .getSelection(keyclicked.target)
          .focusNode.wholeText.toLowerCase()
      );
      let newsorting = sortOptions;
      if (sortOptions.first !== "") {
        newsorting.second = document
          .getSelection(keyclicked.target)
          .focusNode.wholeText.toLowerCase();
      } else {
        newsorting.first = document
          .getSelection(keyclicked.target)
          .focusNode.wholeText.toLowerCase();
      }
      setSortOptions(newsorting);
      selectSorter(
        document
          .getSelection(keyclicked.target)
          .focusNode.wholeText.toLowerCase()
      );
    }
  }, [keyclicked]);

  const renderHeader = () => {
    let headerElement = ["id", "name", "email", "phone", "operation"];

    return headerElement.map((key, index) => {
      return (
        <th onClick={setKeyclicked} key={index}>
          {key.toUpperCase()}
        </th>
      );
    });
  };

  const renderBody = () => {
    console.log("renderBody-employees: ", employees);

    return employees.map(({ id, name, email, phone }) => {
      return (
        <tr key={id}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>{email}</td>
          <td>{phone}</td>
          <td className="operation">
            <button className="button" onClick={() => removeData(id)}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1 id="title">Table</h1>
      <h3>
        {" "}
        Lets go for a <FaBeer /> ?{" "}
      </h3>
      <table id="employee">
        <thead>
          <tr>{renderHeader()}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{renderBody()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

This is from `App.js` :

```
import Table from "./Table";

  const [selectedSortingOption, SetSelectedSortingOption] = React.useState(
    null
  );


  return (
<div className="App">
  <div align="center">
    <button onClick={addSingleEmployee}>AddEmployee</button>

    <Select
      defaultValue={selectedSortingOption}
      onChange={SetSelectedSortingOption}
      options={sortingOptions}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="scrollable">
    <Table
      table_data={sortedData}
      row_data={newEmployee}
      basePageLink={""}
      removeData={removeRaw}
      selectSorter={selectHowToSort}
    />
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <button onClick={emptyTable}>EmptyTable</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

);
}

When clicking on the `email` header for example I get this output in the console log:

```
`email` : which is correct
```

and this `warning` - error message:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Table`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Table`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
Table@https://oqx8ut.csb.app/src/Table/index.jsx:23:15
div
div
App@https://oqx8ut.csb.app/src/App.js:168:33
```

`Table/index.jsx:23` refers to this line:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setEmployees(table_data);
    return () => {
      // clean-up function
    };
  }, [table_data]);
```

while `App.js:168` refers to this:

```
  const [selectedSortingOption, SetSelectedSortingOption] = React.useState(
    null
  );
```

I tried also to do this in the `Child Component` `"Table"` :

```
const [sortOptions, setSortOptions] = React.useState({
    first: "",
    second: ""
  });

  //const modalFunct = (key_clicked) => {
  const modalFunct = React.useMemo(() => {
    //console.log(keyclicked.target);
    //console.log(document.getSelection(keyclicked.target).focusNode);
    if (document.getSelection(keyclicked.target).focusNode !== null) {
      console.log(
        //selectSorter(
        document
          .getSelection(keyclicked.target)
          .focusNode.wholeText.toLowerCase()
      );
      let newsorting = sortOptions;
      if (sortOptions.first !== "") {
        newsorting.second = document
          .getSelection(keyclicked.target)
          .focusNode.wholeText.toLowerCase();
      } else {
        newsorting.first = document
          .getSelection(keyclicked.target)
          .focusNode.wholeText.toLowerCase();
      }
      setSortOptions(newsorting);
      //selectSorter(
        //document
          //.getSelection(keyclicked.target)
          //.focusNode.wholeText.toLowerCase()
      //);
    }
  }, [keyclicked]);

  const memoizedSelectSorter = React.useMemo(() => {
    selectSorter(sortOptions);
  }, [sortOptions]);
```

but still get the same error

What am I doing wrong? How to pass the `email` info (the info about which header has been clicked) from the `Child component` `"Table"` to the `Parent Component` `"App"` where the data is going to be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

You search in your code this line: `return employees.map(({ id, name, email, phone }) => {`, you put return before Array.map() will give you array not a JSX syntax. Try to remove return in that line:

```
    const renderBody = () => {
    console.log("renderBody-employees: ", employees);

    return employees.map(({ id, name, email, phone }) => { //<== remove this return here, put "?" in employees?.map to prevent crash app
      return (
        <tr key={id}>
          <td>{id}</td>
           ....
```

Maybe `table_data` in your `dependency` make `Table` Component infinity re-render cause React busy to render this component, try to remove it:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        setEmployees(table_data);
        return () => {
          // clean-up function
        };
      }, []); // <== Had remove table_data in dependency
```

Comment: I tried in this way: `    employees.map(({id, name, email, phone}) => {
      return ( ...  })` without succeeding

Comment: @Raphael10 Maybe table_data dependency in useEffect() make that error, try remove it. I have updated my post above.

Comment: Unfortunately it still give the following `Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Table`)`